# Creating a set of instances involving float

Tags: python, floating-point, set

I have a class having list of floats x (and y, generated from x, so if x is equivalent, y is also equivalent). Once initialized, the instance does not change. I would like to make a set of the instances (to use `.add()`), so I tried to make the class hashable:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self.x))
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return (
            self.__class__ == other.__class__ and
            self.x == other.x
            )
```

But because of the floating point inaccuracy, the set will recognize two very close instances as different. I would like to set the `__eq__` to be something like

```
    def __eq__(self,other):
        diff = np.max(np.asarray(self.x)-np.asarray(other.x))
        if diff<1e-6:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

but this does not solve the floating point problem.
I could use a tuple `(x,y)` for this problem, but I do not need to compare `y`, and the real class I work on is a little more complicated.

Comment: the inputs are not human generated so I don't think decimal module would be effective. For a more simple example, how does one deal with adding lists like [-185.49374999999998, -8.163433962088037] and [-185.49374999999998, -8.163433962088044] to a set?

Comment: Distinguishing numbers based on them being close together is problematic, because it is not transitive. Suppose you try and put three numbers in a set, and each is _close to_ the previous, but the last is not close to the first. What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: If all are within the tolerance level, I expect all to be considered the "same". Certainly, as Rebelchon commented, the tolerance level must be user specified. And looking at the data, it looks like 1e-9 is a bit too strict.

Comment: No, what I was asking was, what if A and B are within tolerance of each other, and B and C are within tolerance of each other, and A and C are _not_ within tolerance of each other. What is the expected behaviour of your set?

Comment: That is a good point. I could assume that the input is separated enough that it rarely happens; the problem being the numerical instability. Or just accept the result arising from the random order - it will only have a minor effect on the quality and performance.

Comment: (a) Why would you assume the input is separated enough? Plain mathematics can produce real numbers that are close to each other just as well as floating-point rounding can. So two numbers might be different but close because they would ideally be the same if calculated with exact arithmetic in floating-point or because they are in fact different but close due to exact mathematics. How can you tell the difference? (b) Why is it acceptable to use a solution with a bug that “rarely happens”? A bug is a bug, and ones that rarely happen can be the most annoying to diagnose and deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `math.isclose` from the [math module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) in the standard library to compare floats, and, perhaps, round (or truncate) the value used to produce the hash to the number of decimals used by default by `isclose`. (this last value could be parametrized)

```
class X:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(round(self.x, 9))  # round the value hashed to match the default of math.isclose

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return (
            self.__class__ == other.__class__ and
            math.isclose(self.x, other.x)
            )
```

Comment: But then your hash is not consistent with equality. Two instances that claim to be equal could have different hashes.

Comment: Good point: perhaps truncate the values used in the hash to match the absolute tolerance of 10^-9 default of `isclose`?

Comment: I can imagine truncation working as long as the hash and equals are written  _consistently_ . Using `math.isclose` for equality is not even transitive.

Comment: Yes, once you start comparing floats for equality, the chain of compromises to make gets longer. The OP must decide what is suitable for his use cases.